# Docker-compose up throws Errors running first time and works ok after second run

Tags: mysql, spring, docker-compose

When I run docker-compose up for the first time it throws Errors and is not working,
after second run everything works fine.
It is looking like something is missing during first run and is available during second run.
I want this working after first run.

These are my config files:

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  api:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "10012:10012"

  database:
    image: mysql
    container_name: database
    environment:
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ***
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ***
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_DATABASE: currencydb
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    depends_on:
      - api
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD target/currency-rest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar .
EXPOSE 10011
CMD java -jar currency-rest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

application.properties:

```
server.port=10012

spring.jpa.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://database:3306/currencydb?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC

spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=***
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
```

Console output after first run:

```
PS C:\Users\wuher\desktop\currency-rest> docker-compose up
docker-compose : Building api
At line:1 char:1
+ docker-compose up
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Building api:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Step 1/4 : FROM openjdk:8
 ---> f8146facf376
Step 2/4 : ADD target/currency-rest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar .
 ---> fd52b0529742
Step 3/4 : EXPOSE 10011
 ---> Running in dba375d741f8
Removing intermediate container dba375d741f8
 ---> 2dd51a3c0782
Step 4/4 : CMD java -jar currency-rest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
 ---> Running in 7d204a8fc8d5
Removing intermediate container 7d204a8fc8d5
 ---> 1010d46a1bb8
Successfully built 1010d46a1bb8
Successfully tagged currency-rest_api:latest
Image for service api was built because it did not already exist. To rebuild this image you must use `docker-compose build` or `docker-compose up --build`.
Creating currency-rest_api_1 ... 
[1A[2KCreating currency-rest_api_1 ... [32mdone[0m[1B
Creating database            ... 
[1A[2KCreating database            ... [32mdone[0m[1B
Attaching to currency-rest_api_1, database
[33mdatabase    |[0m 2020-01-12 23:44:32+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.18-1debian9 started.
[33mdatabase    |[0m 2020-01-12 23:44:32+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
[33mdatabase    |[0m 2020-01-12 23:44:32+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.18-1debian9 started.
[33mdatabase    |[0m 2020-01-12 23:44:32+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
[33mdatabase    |[0m 2020-01-12T23:44:32.472398Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future rele
ase.
[33mdatabase    |[0m 2020-01-12T23:44:32.472481Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.18) initializing of server in progress as process 45
[36mapi_1       |[0m 
[36mapi_1       |[0m   .   ____          _            __ _ _
[36mapi_1       |[0m  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
[36mapi_1       |[0m ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
[36mapi_1       |[0m  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
[36mapi_1       |[0m   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
[36mapi_1       |[0m  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
[36mapi_1       |[0m  :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.2.RELEASE)
[36mapi_1       |[0m 
[36mapi_1       |[0m 2020-01-12 23:44:32.707  INFO 6 --- [           main] p.k.c.CurrencyRestApplication            : Starting CurrencyRestApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on b5facd58e175 with PID 6 (/currency-rest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by root in /)
[36mapi_1       |[0m 2020-01-12 23:44:32.750  INFO 6 --- [           main] p.k.c.CurrencyRestApplication            : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
[36mapi_1       |[0m 2020-01-12 23:44:33.783  INFO 6 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
[36mapi_1       |[0m 2020-01-12 23:44:33.904  INFO 6 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 104ms. Found 3 JPA repository interfaces.
[36mapi_1       |[0m 2020-01-12 23:44:34.426  INFO 6 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotat
ion.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
[36mapi_1       |[0m 2020-01-12 23:44:34.822  INFO 6 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 10012 (http)
[36mapi_1       |[0m 2020-01-12 23:44:34.841  INFO 6 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
[36mapi_1       |[0m 2020-01-12 23:44:34.841  INFO 6 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.29]
[33mdatabase    |[0m 2020-01-12T23:44:35.145873Z 5 [Warning] [MY-010453] [Server] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
[36mapi_1       |[0m 2020-01-12 23:44:35.391  INFO 6 --- [           main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner     : At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were sc
anned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
[36mapi_1       |[0m 2020-01-12 23:44:35.697  INFO 6 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
[36mapi_1       |[0m 2020-01-12 23:44:35.697  INFO 6 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2840 ms
[36mapi_1       |[0m 2020-01-12 23:44:36.207  INFO 6 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
[36mapi_1       |[0m 2020-01-12 23:44:36.293  INFO 6 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.4.9.Final}
[36mapi_1       |[0m 2020-01-12 23:44:36.499  INFO 6 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
[36mapi_1       |[0m 2020-01-12 23:44:36.665  INFO 6 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
[36mapi_1       |[0m 2020-01-12 23:44:36.770 ERROR 6 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
[36mapi_1       |[0m 
[36mapi_1       |[0m com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
[36mapi_1       |[0m 
[36mapi_1       |[0m The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
[36mapi_1       |[0m  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
[36mapi_1       |[0m  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~]
/////
cut part of code
/////
[36mapi_1       |[0m Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
[36mapi_1       |[0m 
[36mapi_1       |[0m The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
[36mapi_1       |[0m  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
[36mapi_1       |[0m  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
[36mapi_1       |[0m  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
[36mapi_1       |[0m  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
[36mapi_1       |[0m  at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
[36mapi_1       |[0m  at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
[36mapi_1       |[0m  at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
[36mapi_1       |[0m  at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
[36mapi_1       |[0m  at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:91) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
[36mapi_1       |[0m  at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:144) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
[36mapi_1       |[0m  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:956) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
[36mapi_1       |[0m  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:826) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
[36mapi_1       |[0m  ... 57 common frames omitted
[36mapi_1       |[0m Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
[36mapi_1       |[0m  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
[36mapi_1       |[0m  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
[36mapi_1       |[0m  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
[36mapi_1       |[0m  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
[36mapi_1       |[0m  at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
[36mapi_1       |[0m  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
[36mapi_1       |[0m  at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:155) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
[36mapi_1       |[0m  at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:65) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
[36mapi_1       |[0m  ... 60 common frames omitted
[36mapi_1       |[0m 
[36mapi_1       |[0m 2020-01-12 23:44:36.771  WARN 6 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Communications link failure
[36mapi_1       |[0m 
[36mapi_1       |[0m The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
[36mapi_1       |[0m 2020-01-12 23:44:36.775  WARN 6 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
 Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceExce
ption: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
[36mapi_1       |[0m 2020-01-12 23:44:36.779  INFO 6 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
[36mapi_1       |[0m 2020-01-12 23:44:36.798  INFO 6 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 
[36mapi_1       |[0m 
[36mapi_1       |[0m Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[36mapi_1       |[0m 2020-01-12 23:44:36.801 ERROR 6 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
///////
cut part of info
///////
[36mcurrency-rest_api_1 exited with code 1
[0m[33mdatabase    |[0m 2020-01-12 23:44:38+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Database files initialized
[33mdatabase    |[0m 2020-01-12 23:44:38+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Starting temporary server
[33mdatabase    |[0m 2020-01-12T23:44:38.668558Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future rele
ase.
[33mdatabase    |[0m 2020-01-12T23:44:38.668651Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.18) starting as process 94
[33mdatabase    |[0m 2020-01-12T23:44:39.078017Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
[33mdatabase    |[0m 2020-01-12T23:44:39.082365Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
[33mdatabase    |[0m 2020-01-12T23:44:39.102708Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.18'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
[33mdatabase    |[0m 2020-01-12 23:44:39+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server started.
[33mdatabase    |[0m 2020-01-12T23:44:39.243716Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock'
[33mdatabase    |[0m Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
[33mdatabase    |[0m Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list' as time zone. Skipping it.
[33mdatabase    |[0m Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
[33mdatabase    |[0m Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone1970.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
[33mdatabase    |[0m 2020-01-12 23:44:41+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating database currencydb
[33mdatabase    |[0m 2020-01-12 23:44:41+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating user user
[33mdatabase    |[0m 2020-01-12 23:44:41+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Giving user user access to schema currencydb
[33mdatabase    |[0m 
[33mdatabase    |[0m 2020-01-12 23:44:41+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Stopping temporary server
[33mdatabase    |[0m 2020-01-12T23:44:41.782901Z 14 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user root. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.18).
[33mdatabase    |[0m 2020-01-12T23:44:43.508856Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.18)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
[33mdatabase    |[0m 2020-01-12 23:44:43+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server stopped
[33mdatabase    |[0m 
[33mdatabase    |[0m 2020-01-12 23:44:43+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: MySQL init process done. Ready for start up.
[33mdatabase    |[0m 
[33mdatabase    |[0m 2020-01-12T23:44:44.029991Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future rele
ase.
[33mdatabase    |[0m 2020-01-12T23:44:44.030080Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.18) starting as process 1
[33mdatabase    |[0m 2020-01-12T23:44:44.448592Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
[33mdatabase    |[0m 2020-01-12T23:44:44.452896Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
[33mdatabase    |[0m 2020-01-12T23:44:44.467507Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.18'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
[33mdatabase    |[0m 2020-01-12T23:44:44.636049Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' bind-address: '::' port: 33060
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As per your `docker-compose` you are expecting your `App` to run before `Database`.

But App has a dependency on `MySQL` and if it's not up `SpringBoot` will throw error.

Please change your `depends_on` configuration like this.

```
version: '3'
services:
  api:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "10012:10012"
    depends_on:
      - database
  database:
    image: mysql
    container_name: database
    environment:
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ***
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ***
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_DATABASE: currencydb
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
```

Refer more in detail [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/). Search for **depends_on**

Comment: @MyTwoCensts I was trying to put depends_on... in database part and api part but it still throws error.

Comment: Add depends_on only in app and remove from database as I have done above.

Comment: Yes I did it before but it didnt help.